# Neo4J in Netbeans: error with Iterator

Tags: java, netbeans, neo4j, iterator, nosql

i'm trying to learn about NoSql databases and would love to integrate it with Netbeans, so i'm trying to make a piece of tutorial code run on my pc. However i encountered an issue right at the end, I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

```
 package com.mycompany.neo4jdemo;

import org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine;
import org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionResult;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Label;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Relationship;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.RelationshipType;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.ResourceIterator;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;
import org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorUtil;
import org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.StringLogger;


public class Main {
    public enum NodeType implements Label
    {
        Person, Course;
    }

    public enum RelationType implements RelationshipType
    {
        Knows, BelongsTo;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        GraphDatabaseFactory dbFactory = new GraphDatabaseFactory();
        GraphDatabaseService graphDb = dbFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase("C:/Users/mifouche/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb");
        //This is the database link given by Neo4j, however is this the correct link?

        ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine(graphDb, StringLogger.SYSTEM);
        ExecutionResult result;

        try(Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx())
        {
            //Clear the database
            engine.execute("match (n) optional match (n)-[r]-() delete n,r");

            //Create Person Bob Node with Properties
            Node bobNode = graphDb.createNode(NodeType.Person);
            bobNode.setProperty("PId", 5001);
            bobNode.setProperty("Name", "Bob");
            bobNode.setProperty("Age", 23);

            //Create Person Alice Node with Properties
            Node aliceNode = graphDb.createNode(NodeType.Person);
            aliceNode.setProperty("PId", 5002);
            aliceNode.setProperty("Name", "Alice");

            //Create Person Eve Node with one Property
            Node eveNode = graphDb.createNode(NodeType.Person);
            eveNode.setProperty("Name", "Eve");

            //Create Course IT Node with properties
            Node itNode = graphDb.createNode(NodeType.Course);
            itNode.setProperty("Id", 1);
            itNode.setProperty("Name", "IT Beginners");
            itNode.setProperty("Location", "Room 153");

            //Create Course Electronics Node with properties
            Node electronicNode = graphDb.createNode(NodeType.Course);
            electronicNode.setProperty("Name", "Electronics Advanced");

            //Set up the relationship between bob and alice
            bobNode.createRelationshipTo(aliceNode, RelationType.Knows);

            //Set up the relationship between bob and the IT course
            Relationship bobRelIt = bobNode.createRelationshipTo(itNode, RelationType.BelongsTo);
            bobRelIt.setProperty("Function", "Student");

            //Set up the relationship between bob and the Electronics course
            Relationship bobRelElectronics = bobNode.createRelationshipTo(electronicNode, RelationType.BelongsTo);
            bobRelElectronics.setProperty("Function", "Supply Teacher");

            //Set up the relationship between alice and the IT course
            Relationship aliceRelIt = aliceNode.createRelationshipTo(itNode, RelationType.BelongsTo);
            aliceRelIt.setProperty("Function", "Teacher");

            //stamp the transaction as successful
            tx.success();

            //Find all the Person nodes on the Neo4J  database
            result = engine.execute("MATCH (n:Person) RETURN n");

            //fill the node columns with the values from the database (I think)
            ResourceIterator<Node> columns = result.columnAs("n");

            //iterate through all the values that was returned
            for(Node node:IteratorUtil.asIterable(columns))
            {
                System.out.println(node + ": "+node.getProperty("Name"));
            }

        }
        graphDb.shutdown();
    }

}
```

The error appears in the line >> ResourceIterator columns = result.columnAs("n");
The error give is: The type of  columnAs(String> is erroneous. As can be seen in this image: 
http://s1294.photobucket.com/user/mfoosh/media/NetbeansNeo4jError_zpsx2ygasqh.png.html

I changed some of the code from the basis tutorial but couldn't find a solution as yet... tutorial can be found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-g-vCsZO_3g

(From this basis I would like to expand my knowledge to be able to read in a dataset in xml/csv format and create a graph database in Neo4j, and from there try and determine various information bits from the findings, any hints towards where i can look to help me?)

Comment: Have you tried telling columnAs what generic parameter to use as T by calling it like this: result.<Node>columnAs("n");

Comment: I'm not sure if i'm implementing your solution correctly, not getting any luck with it, but the solution posted by @Sumit did the trick. I can now get the records from the Neo4j database :)

Comment: your original was also OK, because ResourceIterator implements Iterator. The problem was the generic parameter. Sumit's solution means you have to cast each object to Node in your loop. But if you use my syntax, columnAs will return ResourceIterator<Node> and you won't have to cast in the loop. Putting the template parameter between the dot and the method name is uncommon syntax: ResourceIterator<Node> columns = result.<Node>columnAs("n");

Answer (score 2):

You have to use "scala.collection.Iterator" for Iterating over the Nodes.

Something like this : -

```
String query = "MATCH (n) return n";
ExecutionResult result = engine.execute(query);
scala.collection.Iterator<Object> objResult = result.columnAs("n");

    while(objResult.hasNext()){
    Node cypherNode = (Node)objResult.next();
.......
}
```

Comment: Sure, Please do not forgot to Vote, if it helps you :)

Comment: I didn't know about this scala Iterator. Thanks Sumit!

Answer (score 0):

Cast it, it should work

```
ResourceIterator<Node> columns = (ResourceIterator<Node>) result.columnAs("n");
```

Comment: Thanks, i have tried this before, it does remove the error, however upon running the project it returns this error:

--- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ neo4jDemo ---

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11 cannot be cast to org.neo4j.graphdb.ResourceIterator

at com.mycompany.neo4jdemo.Main.main(Main.java:98)

Answer (score 0):

While both given answers address your issue to the full extent, I'd suggest using something like this:

```
graphDb.findNodes(Person); // no casting, no cypher engine usage
```

[Here's an API link.](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService.html#findNodes(org.neo4j.graphdb.Label))